# MongoDB organize paggination with bucket pattern

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Hello i use bucket pattern for collection , bucket by 10 count

```
{
    blog_id: 12345,
    created: '2021-10-03'
    posts: [
       {
             post_id: 222,
             text: 'wasd',
             created: '2021-10-10'
       },
       … 
    ],
   post_count: 10,
}
```

On site i first show newest(latest) posts 10 count per page. its all okey if buckets full
10 | 10 | 10 | 10

buy late i add new post and created new bucket
1 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10

now if i take 1 bucket i get 1 post ! but we have more

what is query i should use for take 10 posts if bucket is not full ?

Comment: do you understand the question? need more information ?

Comment: or this problem havent resolve ?